# SQL Sum of Points by Company and Team where users have points, company, team

Tags: sql

I have tables User, Points, Team and Company.

Users are apart of a team and a company.
Teams are associated to a company.
Points are associated to users.

What would be the best plan of attack to list total points for a team and for a company?

```
User Table
UserId|CompanyId|TeamId
1     |1        |1
2     |1        |1
3     |1        |2
4     |2        |3
5     |2        |3
6     |2        |3

Team Table
TeamId|TeamName|CompanyId
1     |a       |1
2     |b       |1
3     |c       |2

Company Table
CompanyId|CompanyName
1        |abc
2        |def

Points Table
PointsId|UserId|Points
1       |1     |3
2       |1     |1
3       |2     |2
4       |3     |3
5       |3     |5
6       |4     |2
7       |5     |3
8       |6     |1
9       |6     |1
```

Example:
User1 is logged in so he needs to see total points for each company, and each team in his company

Which in this case lets say userId 1 is logged in

Query one - total points for each company:

```
Company 1 Has 3 users and they have 5 different points associated to the users
Company 1 Sum Points = (3 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5) = 14
Company 2 Has 3 users and they have 4 different points associated to their users
Company 2 Sum Points = (2 + 3 + 1 + 1) = 7
```

Query two - Sum of points for each team within the company of the logged in user:
UserId 1 is in CompanyId 1 which has 2 teams

```
Team 1 has 2 Users (userId 1,2)
Team 1 Sum Points: (3 + 1 + 2) = 6
Team 2 has 1 User ( userId 3 )
Team 2 Sum Points: (3 + 5) = 8
```

I was considering including the companyId and TeamId in the points table then querying based on that but it seemed like such a hacky way of solving this.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Phrased a little differently:  the best plan of attack is to figure out what you want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, changed it up hopefully this provides more clarity.

Comment: Table design seems ok at first look.  Especially since points only apply to a user.  When we want to get Team or Company totals, we would do the joins...  We probably don't need/want to know there are "5 different points ROWS associated to the users"...etc  seems meaningless to talk about ROWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries will do what you want. I've put the summation from `Points` into a subquery as it simplifies the `JOIN`:

```
 SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(u.UserId) AS users, SUM(p.scores) AS scores, SUM(p.Points) AS points
  FROM User u
  JOIN Company c ON c.CompanyID = u.CompanyID
  JOIN (SELECT UserId, COUNT(PointsId) AS scores, SUM(Points) AS Points
        FROM Points p
        GROUP BY UserId) p
        ON p.UserId = u.UserID
  GROUP BY c.CompanyId;
```

Output:

```
CompanyName     users   scores  points
abc             3       5       14
def             3       4       7
```

Query 2:

```
 SELECT t.TeamName, COUNT(u.userId) AS users, SUM(p.Points) AS points
  FROM Team t
  JOIN User u ON u.TeamId = t.TeamId
  JOIN (SELECT UserId, COUNT(PointsId) AS scores, SUM(Points) AS Points
        FROM Points p
        GROUP BY UserId) p
        ON p.UserId = u.UserID
  GROUP BY t.TeamId
```

Output:

```
TeamName    users   points
a           2       6
b           1       8
c           3       7
```

If you want to restrict the list of teams to a particular company, add e.g. `AND u.CompanyId = 1` to the `JOIN` on `User` e.g.

```
SELECT t.TeamName, COUNT(u.userId) AS users, SUM(p.Points) AS points
  FROM Team t
  JOIN User u ON u.TeamId = t.TeamId AND u.CompanyId = 1
  JOIN (SELECT UserId, COUNT(PointsId) AS scores, SUM(Points) AS Points
        FROM Points p
        GROUP BY UserId) p
        ON p.UserId = u.UserID
  GROUP BY t.TeamId;
```

Output:

```
TeamName    users   points
a           2       6
b           1       8
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3aa1dd/16)

Comment: Thanks Nick! Trying this out now, my joins were giving incorrect summations but this looks logically sound!

Comment: Yes - the one-to-many relationship from `User` to `Points` makes doing the sums tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Left join `user` and `points` to `company`. `GROUP BY` the company to get the sum of points per company using `sum()`. This gets you the pointy per company.

```
SELECT c1.companyid,
       c1.companyname,
       coalesce(sum(p1.points), 0)
       FROM company c1
            LEFT JOIN user u1
                      ON u1.companyid = c1.companyid
            LEFT JOIN points p1
                      ON p1.userid = u1.userid
       GROUP BY c1.companyid,
                c1.companyname;
```

Inner join `user`, `company` and `team` to get the teams of the company a user belongs to. Left join the users of the teams and their points. `GROUP BY` the team to get the sum of points per company using `sum()`. Limit it to user 1 with a `WHERE` clause. This gets you the points per team of the company of user user 1.

```
SELECT t1.teamid,
       t1.teamname,
       coalesce(sum(p1.points), 0)
       FROM user u1
            INNER JOIN company c1
                       ON c1.companyid = u1.companyid
            INNER JOIN team t1
                       ON t1.companyid = c1.companyid
            LEFT JOIN user u2
                      ON u2.teamid = t1.teamid
            LEFT JOIN points p1
                      ON p1.userid = u2.userid
       WHERE u1.userid = 1
       GROUP BY t1.teamid,
                t1.teamname;
```